# How to crypt and decrypt data between Ruby and Android applications?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, cryptography, client-server

I've been developing a web server application using Ruby on Rails and a client one with Android. The web server has some routes to client access, with no authentication. I thought creating a token to verify if the request is from client or not. I imagine a solution like this:

1. Create a key, for example, "stackoverflow;
2. Share this key in client and server application;
3. Generate a token using AES cryptography with a generate random String function + key;
4. When the client app is sending a request to server, send also the generated token;
5. Server verifies if token is valid or not using the shared key and AES cryptography.

Here are my doubts:

1. Is this the best way to develop a communication between them?
2. Is there a gem/api crypt and decrypt to use in both systems?

Please, do not hesitate to describe a suggestion or examples to guide me =)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A more secure and standard way would be to use SSL client certificates.

Issue a client certificate for every new version of your app, make sure it is signed using a certificate (ie CA cert) of which only you, or your signing CA has the private key.

Setup your web server to require client certificates before allowing the connection. Set the web server to verify the certificates agains the CA certificate you hold.

This way there is no "shared secret" that can be extracted from your app. If someone extracts and steals the client certificate, issue an updated version of your app with a new certificate,  next add the old certificate to the revocation list of you CA, or just tell the web server to block that specific one.

No ruby, java or javascript code to be written.

Comment: Thanks for reply Tim, I'm going to study how it works and its implementation. If you have good tutorials to suggest, please tell me.

Comment: This is not quite correct. Normally the client keypair is *generated* by the client app and a certificate is created from the public key. The client app (and only the client app) must have access to the private key for this client certificate.

Comment: Yep you are correct, that is the normal scenario, but in this case, since you will be issuing one client cert to be shared by many app users, and since you do control both sides of the coin, the client app  just needs a signed cert you can verify and revoke. If you were to issue a certificate per user, then it would be more reasonable to let each user generate their own certs with their own keypairs.